# Rails 4 Broken Link Using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm attempting to add a 'recommendations' section to a mock profile page using ajax. When I click on the Recommendations button--on the coding_skills index page-- I get zero server or log errors but the page stays on the index page and does not load the 'recommendations' page. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

## Recommendations Controller

```
class RecommendationsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @recommendations = Recommendation.all
  end

  def new
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new
  end

  def create
    @recommendation = Recommendation.new(recommendation_params)
    @recommendation.recommendation_author = current_user.email
    if @recommendation.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to coding_skills_url }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def recommendation_params
    params.require(:recommendation).permit(:recommendation_content)
  end
end
```

## Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "coding_skills#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :posts
  resources :coding_skills do
    resources :projects
  end

  resources :recommendations
end
```

## Views#index

```
<%= render "best_of" %>
```

## _Best_of.html.erb

```
<div id="best_of">
  <h1>Recommendations for Cody</h1>

  <p>Add a recommendation below!</p>

    <% if current_user %>
    <%= link_to "Add a recommendation", new_recommendation_path, class: "btn btn-success", remote: true %>
    <% else %>
    <p><%= link_to "Sign in to add a recommendation", new_user_session_path %></p>
    <% end %>



  <h3>Recommendations</h3>
  <div id="recommendations">
    <% if @recommendations.any? %>
      <%= render(@recommendations) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>



  <%= link_to "Close", root_path, id: "hide_best_of", class: "btn btn-success" %>

  </div>
```

## _form.html.erb

```
<div id="recommendation-header">
  <h3>Hey there, <%= current_user.email %>!</h3>
</div>

<%= bootstrap_form_for @recommendation, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :recommendation_content, label: "What do you like about Cody?" %>
  <%= f.submit "Add recommendation", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

## Rake Routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                 Controller#Action
                     root GET    /                                                           coding_skills#index
         new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                    devise/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                    devise/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                   devise/sessions#destroy
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                   devise/passwords#create
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                               devise/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                              devise/passwords#edit
                          PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                   devise/passwords#update
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                   devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                     devise/registrations#cancel
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#create
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                    devise/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                       devise/registrations#edit
                          PATCH  /users(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#update
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#update
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                                            devise/registrations#destroy
                    posts GET    /posts(.:format)                                            posts#index
                          POST   /posts(.:format)                                            posts#create
                 new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                                        posts#new
                edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                                   posts#edit
                     post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                                        posts#show
                          PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                                        posts#update
                          PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                                        posts#update
                          DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                                        posts#destroy
    coding_skill_projects GET    /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects(.:format)          projects#index
                          POST   /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects(.:format)          projects#create
 new_coding_skill_project GET    /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_coding_skill_project GET    /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
     coding_skill_project GET    /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
                          PATCH  /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
                          PUT    /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
                          DELETE /coding_skills/:coding_skill_id/projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
            coding_skills GET    /coding_skills(.:format)                                    coding_skills#index
                          POST   /coding_skills(.:format)                                    coding_skills#create
         new_coding_skill GET    /coding_skills/new(.:format)                                coding_skills#new
        edit_coding_skill GET    /coding_skills/:id/edit(.:format)                           coding_skills#edit
             coding_skill GET    /coding_skills/:id(.:format)                                coding_skills#show
                          PATCH  /coding_skills/:id(.:format)                                coding_skills#update
                          PUT    /coding_skills/:id(.:format)                                coding_skills#update
                          DELETE /coding_skills/:id(.:format)                                coding_skills#destroy
          recommendations GET    /recommendations(.:format)                                  recommendations#index
                          POST   /recommendations(.:format)                                  recommendations#create
       new_recommendation GET    /recommendations/new(.:format)                              recommendations#new
      edit_recommendation GET    /recommendations/:id/edit(.:format)                         recommendations#edit
           recommendation GET    /recommendations/:id(.:format)                              recommendations#show
                          PATCH  /recommendations/:id(.:format)                              recommendations#update
                          PUT    /recommendations/:id(.:format)                              recommendations#update
                          DELETE /recommendations/:id(.:format)                              recommendations#destroy
```

Comment: 1) which "recommendations" button are you clicking on (you have several links and buttons and none of them seem to just say "Recommendations" 2) are you using chrome and/or firefox? have you done a right-click and inspect the page? what happens in the network tab? what about the javascript console?

Comment: When you wrote, "When I click on the Recommendations button," were you referring to the "Add a recommendation" button?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of info. Yes, I was referring to the 'Add a recommendation' button on the _best_of.html.erb file.

Comment: @Taryn, I'm using Chrome. I get zero errors in the javascript console. I've never used the network tab, but I opened it up just now and it doesn't display any info. The button works if I remove the 'remote: true' as suggested below in Brian's response, but this also does away with the Ajax functionality!

Comment: For the network tab, you have to open the tab, then refresh the page in order to actually see anything. Network will show all the gets/etc for your page, including AJAX requests. if there's a 500 error for an ajax request, it'll usually appear in red - you can then click on it to see what the exact request and response was - which lets you see the 500 error and often the full stacktrace, which is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are missing create.js.erb file which would look something like this:

```
$('#element_id').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'your_partial') %>");
```

element_id is the html selector that you want to replace on your page. It depends on how your html looks and what part of it you want to replace during ajax call.

your_partial is the partial you did not provide.

I think instead of escape_javascript you can use just "j".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is on this line:

```
<%= link_to "Add a recommendation", new_recommendation_path, class: "btn btn-success", remote: true %>
```

The `remote: true` at the end causes the HTTP request to be [sent as an AJAX request, with the `Accept` header requesting a JavaScript response](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#link-to).

To fix this, try removing the `remote: true`. Then your redirect should be followed.